# Is it better to use CSS Grid, Flexbox or Table for a complex printable layout that doesn't break when unresponsive?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, print-css

## How do I make this kind of layout using css? Also, It should be printable as it looks.

I have thought about making this using table but as I have started I am feeling that it'll be extreemly painful to make this using table. Now I'm exploring flexbox and grid but it seems that I am pretty much confused about which one to use.

This design also needs to be unresponsive as breaking the layout will be unreadable. It should print as it looks.

[Please take a look at the layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6RM3.jpg)

I'm a beginner in CSS. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Just asking, does the person whose name is written in the bill satisfied with their information being posted publicly on StackOverflow?

Comment: Actually, I have found it on the internet. Can I remove/blur the name and necessary information, and attach it here?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely do that, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this mostly relates to page structure, I'm more leaning towards nested HTML tables. I think you'd be safe using a strictly defined grid as well, but this use case seems to be one of the few where using a table would actually be appropriate.

Remember, the [purpose](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) of an HTML `table` is to "represent tabular data". I would say you data looks awfully tabular.

Yes, this will probably be fairly painful to build. But I think that such a complex layout will be painful regardless of which solution you choose. Might as well choose the correct one.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. I think I should get to know about the flexbox and grid too so that I don't regret my decision later.

Comment: I would definitely recommend learning both. They are incredibly useful module's that each serve a specific purpose.